# Динамическая библиотека

Tags: c#, dll

Не знаю как сделать такое
Есть файл .exe и dll в ней MessageBox функция.
Она лежит в папке data как указать к ней путь,и вызвать функцию.

Comment: Ваша dll нативная или .net?

Comment: Моя,тоже на C# написана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET связывание с другими dll-ками организовано по-другому. Вы должны во время компиляции [указать *зависимость*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx): exe-проект зависит от dll-проекта. Когда вы укажете зависимость, вам станут доступны классы зависимого проекта.

Это уже будет работать из-под Visual Studio, поскольку при компиляции dll будет автоматически скопирована в каталог с exe. Если вы хотите запустить программу отдельно, проще всего скопировать exe и dll в один каталог.

Answer (score 1):

Подключить ее к проекту как референс.